# Removing Single Character Substring and Not in List

Tags: python, pandas, string

I can effectively remove single characters from `source_string`, however how do I include the condition to not remove single characters that are in the list `compass`?

```
compass = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
source_string = 'Florida W Campus A B CD'
' '.join([x for x in source_string.split() if (len(x)>1)])

>>> 'Florida Campus CD'
```

Desired Result:

```
>>> 'Florida W Campus'
```

Edit: I need to add multiple characters in string 'Florida W Campus A B CD'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> ' '.join([x for x in source_string.split() if (len(x)>1) or x in compass])
'Florida W Campus CD'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, however i made an edit to the string to include additional letters

Comment: I need to remove all single characters and multiple characters where they are not in the compass list

Comment: No idea what that means. "Florida" is multiple characters but not removed. "CD" is multiple characters - why are your removing it? Please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
compass = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
addl_strs = ['A', 'B', 'CD']
keep_strs = set(compass).union(set(addl_strs))
' '.join(list(filter(lambda x:len(x) > 1 if x not in keep_strs else x, source_string.split())))
```

You can add more strings if you want using another list and form a set to see if its there to check length.

Comment: Thanks, this works, however i made an edit to the string to include additional letters

Comment: If you want to add additional letters, how about adding them as I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: There are hundreds of combinations in `addl_strs`

Comment: @Starbucks you need to clearly specify your problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
compass = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
source_string = 'Florida W Campus A B'
' '.join([x for x in source_string.split() if x in compass or (len(x)>1)])
```